# Templates for Richfaces4 pages

Tags: richfaces, demo

I am trying some sample of richfaces4 in tomcat7.
If I copy the code in the "view source" of http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panel&skin=emeraldTown to a test.xhtml file. If I go to `http://localhost/jsf-blank/test.jsf`. I will just see a web page with PLAIN TEXT, not the panel shown in the demo...

I found 2 ways to make it like the demo page.

The first way is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <--!!!insert rich:panel tags here!!!-->
</h:body>
</html>
```

The second way is:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
 xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

 <f:view>
 <h:head></h:head>
 <h:body>
    <--!!!insert rich:panel tags here!!!-->   
 </h:body>
 </f:view>

</ui:composition>
```

**Question:**
Could someone explain in more depth why the above 2 pieces of code work but the code directly from the demo does not work???
**Looks like the  tag is the key to render the components.** Someone asked the similar question here [RichFaces4 don't render the components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758434/richfaces4-dont-render-the-components)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find answer in Java EE 6 Tutorial in section "Using Facelets Templates":
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html

What you see when you click "View source" link is code of a client page so you need also a template.